# getting a list of running non-daemon threads in jvisualvm

Tags: java, multithreading, daemon, jvisualvm

I am troubleshooting a shutdown that is not as graceful as it should be, so I would like to get a list of running non-daemon threads in jvisualvm (or other) to hunt the culprit.

Comment: You can just press ctrl+break to get a listing of all running threads with addtional information - not the most comfortable tool but guaranteed to work and does what you need.

Comment: Thanks! (note to myself: it is `ctrl-\' on Linux)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**jstack**  dumps all threads, there is a text that would tell if it is daemon or not

( **jvisualvm** produces same output in 'ThreadDump'- [See this link for more useful documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/threads.html)

```
 "Reference Handler" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00a98400 nid=0x1ee8 in Object.wait() [0x00b6f000]
           java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
                at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
                at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485)
                at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:116)
                - locked <0x19835fa0> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
    
    "VM Thread" prio=10 tid=0x00a95800 nid=0x264 runnable
```

Comment: I think, you mean `jstack`, not `jstat`